# Delete array elements from another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, optimization

I got 2 **arrays**:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
```

I want to delete every **b** element in **a**, in order for a to have `[1,2,3]`

Of course, my real arrays are different.

I want a beautiful answer with a simple method, since I can resolve this issue by using this loop, but I find it ugly.

```
b.each do |e|
  a.delete(e) if a.include?(e)
end
return a
```

It seems that `reject` may be the way to go, but couldn't find the good way. Thanks you

Comment: do `a-b` to get what you wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do as below using [`Array Difference`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-2D) :-

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
a = a - b
a # => [1,2,3]
```

But I would suggest, don't modify the source array. Rather do

```
new_ary = a - b
```

Comment: Beautiful ! Thanks,
Accepted; could you tell me how to use the `reject` method by the way please (is it possible to use it here) ?

Comment: @sidney You can use - `a.reject { |e| b.include?(e)` } .. But `Array#-` is perfect for this.